# How to append sorted data in new csv file

Tags: python-3.7

"i want to sort data in interval and save it to new csv file with same old file indexes,please help"

```
b=0
i=0

sorted_data=[]


for i in range(0,int (max_ht),interval):
     s=df[(df['   Height'] >b) & (df['   Height'] <= i)]
     b=i

     sorted_data.append(s)
     sorted_data=pd.DataFrame( sorted_data)
     sorted_data.to_csv(" sorted_data")
```

i got error /home/Ami/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/range.py:465: RuntimeWarning: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str', sort order is undefined for incomparable objects
  return self._int64index.union(other)